# Can I import a column from one Google Sheets sheet to another, but with distinct filter?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've tried using the `ARRAYFORMULA('NamedRange')`

However, the items a duplicated on the other sheet and I only want to import one entry of each item (filtered as distinct).

Answer (score 0):

I used `UNIQUE('NamedRange')` - seems like it's working.

If anyone has a different way of doing this, please comment.